# xrandr thinks same monitor is connected twice

Tags: display, xrandr

So, I have an issue that I think stems from when I made a profile (or whatever you make for xrandr, mode?) to allow for higher resolution than was by default being supported (for some reason it was stuck 800x600, and I wanted 1920x1080).

But now, I have the same monitor show up twice in my xrandr as being connected through two ports; typing `xrandr` gives

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     74.76    70.00    59.98    59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00    75.00    70.00    60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   960x720       75.00    60.00  
   928x696       75.00    60.05  
   896x672       75.05    60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       74.96    69.88    60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       74.76    70.06    59.98  
   640x512       75.02    60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    75.00    72.81    75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       75.00    75.00    70.00    60.06  
   512x384       75.03    70.07    60.00  
   416x312       74.66  
   400x300       72.19    75.12    60.32    56.34  
   320x240       72.81    75.00    60.05  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm x 270mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

The first entry, `eDP-1` is the same monitor. If I look in my "display" section, I see the same monitor listed twice, however that one doesn't actually work. My question is, how can I fix this so that only 1 monitor shows up in my "display"?

Also, my display is using `D-SUB`, so I don't really understand the `eDP-1` and `DP-1` thing.

My monitor has `D-SUB`, `HDMI` and `DVI-D` ports on it. Currently it's connected by the `D-SUB`.

Hardware/Computer information - i6700k (Skylake), Debian 9.

Comment: Tell us what hardware you have... PC/laptop, what types of display output connectors does it have. Your monitor, what types of input connectors does it have?

Comment: What bad effect does this cause? You could always try `xrandr --output [undesired display] --off`